# Ubuntu 16.04 Boot Alternates Between Freezing and Working

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

At present, when trying to boot to Ubuntu 16.04, it alternately freezes or works fine.

On the occassions when it freezes, it gets to the "Please Unlock disk sda5_crypt2 screen. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> takes me to a flashing prompt, and nothing happens if I type.

If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I can type stuff that appears on screen and press enter (upon which I go to a new line), but nothing happens.

If I reboot the machine, it will boot to Ubuntu OK, though the loading screens are of low resolution.

The problems occured when I installed nVidia Cuda Toolkit 8.0, which caused my PC to freeze when booting. After that, I had to use boot options to boot to recovery mode and console, using these commands to fix it:

```
apt-get purge fglrx -y
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

What can I do to try booting successfully every time?

Is there anything I should look for in `/var/log/syslog`?

My system is a Dell Precision 7500 with Quadro 4000.

Edit: Adding contents from /var/log/syslog...

I tried capturing syslog when it fails to boot and when it doesn't fail to boot. It doesn't seem to get to the stage where it creates a log file when it fails to boot. The screen it freezes on is the ""Please Unlock disk sda5_crypt2" screen.

The head of the log when it does boot is below (I can't paste the full log due to the 30k character limit). Is there any clue as to it know it failed on the previous attempt?

```
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="1591" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-57-generic (buildd@lgw01-54) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-57.78-generic 4.4.35)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd-modules-load[642]: Inserted module 'lp'
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'lazy' FPU context switches.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd-modules-load[642]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009dbff] usable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.softdep: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000d7df9bff] usable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d7df9c00-0x00000000d7e4bbff] ACPI NVS
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d7e4bc00-0x00000000d7e4dbff] ACPI data
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000d7e4dc00-0x00000000d7ffffff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fcffffff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.symbols.bin: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fed003ff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000feefffff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.builtin.bin: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffb00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modprobe.d/blacklist_linux_4.4.0-31-generic.conf: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000001827ffffff] usable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.5 present.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Tue Dec 27 19:03:50 2016 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.dep.bin: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: Dell Inc. Precision WorkStation T7500  /06FW8P, BIOS A10 04/20/2011
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.alias.bin: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x1828000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 loadkeys[648]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR default type: write-back
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   00000-9FFFF write-back
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   C0000-DBFFF write-protect
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DC000-EFFFF uncachable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   F0000-FFFFF write-protect
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   0 base 00D7F00000 mask FFFFF00000 uncachable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   1 base 00D8000000 mask FFF8000000 uncachable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   2 base 00E0000000 mask FFE0000000 uncachable
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   3 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   4 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   5 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   6 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   7 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   8 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   9 disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WC  UC- WT  
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0xd7df9 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000097000] 97000 size 24576
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Using GB pages for direct mapping
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BRK [0x0220a000, 0x0220afff] PGTABLE
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BRK [0x0220b000, 0x0220bfff] PGTABLE
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BRK [0x0220c000, 0x0220cfff] PGTABLE
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] BRK [0x0220d000, 0x0220dfff] PGTABLE
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x3332e000-0x3598efff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000FEC30 000024 (v02 DELL  )
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000000FCAF5 000084 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000000FCBED 0000F4 (v03 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/Gpe0Block: 128/64 (20150930/tbfadt-623)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000FFE9ED53 005908 (v01 DELL   dt_ex    00001000 INTL 20050624)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000D7DF9C00 000040
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000D7DF9C00 000040
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000FFEA476C 00009C (v01 DELL   st_ex    00001000 INTL 20050624)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000000FCCE1 00026A (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: BOOT 0x00000000000FCF4B 000028 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: ASF! 0x00000000000FCF73 000096 (v32 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000000FD009 00003C (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000000FD045 000038 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: TCPA 0x00000000000FD2A1 000032 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: ____ 0x00000000000FD2D3 000030 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: _RAT 0x00000000000FDED5 000030 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd-modules-load[642]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 0x00000000000FD07D 000176 (v01 DELL   B10K     00000015 ASL  00000061)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000D7E4DC00 004104 (v01 INTEL  PPM RCM  80000001 INTL 20061109)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000001827ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x1827ff9000-0x1827ffdfff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000001827ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Device   empty
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009cfff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000d7df8fff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Braille Device Support.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000001827ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000001827ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 25165205
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 21 pages reserved
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3996 pages, LIFO batch:0
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 13752 pages used for memmap
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32 zone: 880121 pages, LIFO batch:31
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 379392 pages used for memmap
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 24281088 pages, LIFO batch:31
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high level lint[0x1])
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 8, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 9, version 32, address 0xfec80000, GSI 24-47
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] IOAPIC[2]: apic_id 10, version 32, address 0xfec88000, GSI 48-71
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a301 base: 0xfed00000
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 64 CPUs, 40 hotplug CPUs
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009d000-0x000effff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3"
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7df9000-0xd7df9fff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7dfa000-0xd7e4afff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7e4b000-0xd7e4bfff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7e4c000-0xd7e4cfff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1"
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.1"
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.4"
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/macintosh/mac_hid.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/wmi.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/block/floppy.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/edac/edac_core.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7e4d000-0xd7e4dfff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_fintek.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7e4e000-0xd7ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/mfd/lpc_ich.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd8000000-0xf7ffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfcffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd000000-0xfdffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe000000-0xfecfffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfedfffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfeefffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/pci/hotplug/shpchp.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfef00000-0xffafffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xffb00000-0xffffffff]
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] e820: [mem 0xd8000000-0xf7ffffff] available for PCI devices
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/edac/i7core_edac.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:512 nr_cpumask_bits:512 nr_cpu_ids:64 nr_node_ids:1
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 33 pages/cpu @ffff8817c6600000 s98264 r8192 d28712 u262144
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s98264 r8192 d28712 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 [0] 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 [0] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 [0] 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 [0] 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 24771976
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] log_buf_len individual max cpu contribution: 4096 bytes
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] log_buf_len total cpu_extra contributions: 258048 bytes
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] log_buf_len min size: 262144 bytes
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] log_buf_len: 524288 bytes
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] early log buf free: 252220(96%)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-device.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 98954748K/100660820K available (8432K kernel code, 1291K rwdata, 3960K rodata, 1484K init, 1316K bss, 1706072K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=64, Nodes=1
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]    Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000]    RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=512 to nr_cpu_ids=64.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=64
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:1752 16
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484882848 ns
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/input/serio/serio_raw.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] hpet clockevent registered
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 3058.952 MHz processor
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000044] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 6117.90 BogoMIPS (lpj=12235808)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000047] pid_max: default: 65536 minimum: 512
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.000060] ACPI: Core revision 20150930
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.085994] ACPI: 3 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.086091] Security Framework initialized
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.086093] Yama: becoming mindful.
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.086133] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.092244] Dentry cache hash table entries: 16777216 (order: 15, 134217728 bytes)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.116729] Inode-cache hash table entries: 8388608 (order: 14, 67108864 bytes)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/virt/lib/irqbypass.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.126933] Mount-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.127043] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.127973] Initializing cgroup subsys io
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.127977] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.127999] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/ghash-clmulni-intel.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128002] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128004] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128006] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128015] Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128019] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128020] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128053] CPU: Physical Processor ID: 1
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128054] CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128060] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128061] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128063] mce: CPU supports 9 MCE banks
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128072] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 ureadahead[645]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko: No such file or directory
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128078] process: using mwait in idle threads
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128084] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 7, 4MB 7
Dec 27 19:03:20 T7500 kernel: [    0.128085] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 512, 2MB 32, 4MB 32, 1GB 0
```

Comment: After a frozen boot and then a successful boot, immediately look into `/var/log/syslog` and scroll back in time to the frozen boot. Report any error messages in your question.

Comment: Related: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?27534-I-can-t-type-on-the-quot-please-unlock-disk-sda5_crypt-quot-screen-on-my-Kali-encrypted-LVM and http://askubuntu.com/questions/249322/unlocking-the-disk-sda5-crypt-enter-passphrase Note that you can always upload a [pastie](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide the link for output above and beyond the character limit. HAve you tried simply entering the decryption passphrase at the Please Unlock screen? You won't see what your typing but if you type it correctly it should unlock.

Comment: Also note that your kernel revision appears to be several versions behind. Have you tried updating after a successful boot?  The output of `dmesg` night also provide some clarity

Comment: It's strange that my kernel version was behind as it was a new installation. Are there any commands that I should run to make it up to date, or does it not really matter?